# Does using kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice forcing me to handle all events?

Tags: macos, hid, iokit

I've been using `IOHIDManager` to capture keyboard strokes and was able to capture them inside `Handle_InputCallback` while using `IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback(manager, Handle_InputCallback, NULL);`

So far I've been able to block all keys from reaching the OS using `kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice` but I don't want to handle all the keyboard actions.

My goal is to filter out just the key `x` and block it from reaching to the OS.

Is there a way for me to block and handle just the `x` key and pass everything else to the OS for it to handle, or am I forced to handle all events for that device once `kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice` is used?