# IOHIDManagerOpen returns error code -536870201

Tags: macos, hid, iokit

I am new to USB usage in my application on Mac. When I log the result of IOHIDManagerOpen(x,y) function call on my application I get error code  -536870201. I have found in the following post ([Keystrokes are not blocked when using kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice and are still passed to the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673002/keystrokes-are-not-blocked-when-using-kiohidoptionstypeseizedevice-and-are-still)) that -536870207 is translated to kIOReturnNotPrivileged. How can I translate my error code and understand the cause of an error?

Code that I am running:

```
  manager = std::make_unique<CoreFoundationReference<IOHIDManagerRef>>(
      IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone));

  IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(manager->Get(), nullptr);
  IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(
      manager->Get(), &MacHidDeviceManager::OnDeviceMatched, this);
  IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(
      manager->Get(), &MacHidDeviceManager::OnDeviceRemoved, this);
  IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(
      manager->Get(), CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

  auto ioResult = IOHIDManagerOpen(manager->Get(), kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
  if (ioResult != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    throw UsbInterfaceException("DeviceManager::DeviceManager", "Cannot open IO device manager, error: {}", ioResult);
  }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the code you added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IOKit return values (`IOReturn`) it's typically much more helpful to print them as hexadecimal, ("0x%x") as that's how the constants are defined in [`<IOKit/IOReturn.h>`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/xnu-8020.121.3/iokit/IOKit/IOReturn.h).

So for example, -536870201 is represented in hexadecimal as `0xE00002C7`. The `0xE0000000` part means it's an IOKit constant, the last few digits of `2C7` [identify it as `kIOReturnUnsupported`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/fdd8201d7b966f0c3ea610489d29bd841d358941/iokit/IOKit/IOReturn.h#L153).

<s>You haven't posted any code or other details about the run-up or arguments to your `IOHIDManagerOpen()` call, so I can't really say why it should return `kIOReturnUnsupported` without more details.</s>

Based on the code you added to your question, I tried to come up with the minimum reproducible sample:

```
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDManager.h>

struct MacHidDeviceManager
{
    static void OnDeviceMatched(void *context, IOReturn result, void *sender, IOHIDDeviceRef device) {}
    static void OnDeviceRemoved(void *context, IOReturn result, void *sender, IOHIDDeviceRef device) {}
    void Start()
    {
        IOHIDManagerRef manager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
        IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(manager, nullptr);
        IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(
            manager, &MacHidDeviceManager::OnDeviceMatched, this);
        IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(
            manager, &MacHidDeviceManager::OnDeviceRemoved, this);
        IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(
            manager, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

        auto ioResult = IOHIDManagerOpen(manager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
        if (ioResult != kIOReturnSuccess) {
            fprintf(stderr, "MacHidDeviceManager -> 0x%x\n", ioResult);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MacHidDeviceManager m;
    m.Start();
}
```

This initially fails (`0xe00002e2`, `kIOReturnNotPermitted`) due to missing consent from Security & Privacy, but succeeds once I've granted that permission in System Preferences. I've tested this on macOS 11 and 13 with the same result. I suspect some of the code you haven't posted (`CoreFoundationReference`?) might be where the problem lies. Or perhaps some sandboxing issue?

Incidentally, I maintain a small library of IOKit helper utilities, and one of those things is a function [`djt_ioreturn_string` which converts `IOReturn` values into string representations of those constants](https://gitlab.com/pmdj/kextgizmos/-/blob/main/ioreturn_strings.cpp#L114). (You just need to include the ioreturn_strings.cpp and ioreturn_strings.h files in your project, the ioreturn_strings.h can be `#include`/`#import`ed from pure C or Objective-C, just the .cpp uses C++.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, based on the vague description in the .h file I would assume that IOHIDManagerOpen is unsupported function which doesn't make much sense. Also what is strange is that it is working on some Mac devices and on some it is not. regarding the code (next message)

Comment: @mrca29 comments aren’t a good way to post code, I recommend you edit your question and add the code there!

Comment: I have mistakenly edited your comment first, please disregard it and/or disapprove it if you can.